# How to do an FFT of a line profile obtained by imagej?

Tags: fft

First of all, I'm a total "signal processing" newbie. So, bear with me.

I know that in ImageJ/Fiji I can use the *Plot Profile* function to select a line profile of an image. Is there a simple way to plot a 1D FFT transform of the data along the line?

If there is a better SO site for this kind of question, please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to do that on imageJ or anywhere? Because if you already have the data along the line then just feed it in your favourite FFT algorithm and voilà

Comment: I wanted to do that, if possible, in ImageJ because of the interactivity. Of course, I could load the 2d array into Fortran, or numpy, or something and fftw it, or fftpack it. However, this would mean that i first need to open up the image, look at where the interesting features are, construct a mask to represent a line and perform the transform. So, if i could combine all of those steps in something as simple as flicking a line over the image, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no straightforward way to do it from the UI. After looking through ImageJ docs and finding out how to start the interpreter, I've come up with something that is essentially this:

```
macro "FFT1D Tool - C099A8877099L0088" {
    profile = getProfile();
    fft=Array.fourier(profile,"None");
    s=newArray(lengthOf(fft));
    for (i=1;i<lengthOf(fft);i++) {
        s[i]=2*PI/i;
    }
    s[0]=0
    Plot.create("Fourier spectrum of the line profile","wavenumber","FFT(line)",s,fft);
    Plot.show();
}
```

If placed in `StartupMacros.fiji.ijm` in the fiji folder, on the next start of fiji, the FFT1D tool will show up in a toolbar menu and, after a line was drawn over the image, a click on the toolbar button will execute the macro.

A caveat: DFT works great for periodic functions and input line sizes that are powers of two. Manually drawing over the image is likely going to result in a non-power-of-two, aperiodic array. Running this through a DFT will result in Gibbs effect which will ruin the accuracy of the transform.    Window functions (substitute "None" for one of the available window functions) can help ameliorate this effect. It helps if the intensity of the image decays towards the endpoints of the profile line.

Also, check this [example](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/macros/examples/TestArrayFourier.txt) of using the Array.fourier function.